# mongoose middleware get document which will be added

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the `findOneAndUpdate()` function with `upsert:true` for a 'create or update' function.
This works fine, but I want an middleware function which calculates some totals based on the data in the document.
That works also fine, if the document exists. 
Based on the notes found in the documentation of mongoose (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) I get the document with the following code:

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function (next) {
  const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery())
})
```

Then I loop through the `docToUpdate.details` to sum up some amounts and set it with `this._update.total = totalSum`

But when adding a new document, the docToUpdate is null, because it's not found yet. Can I access the document which needs to be added in the middleware, and how?

This is my full code.

Controller:

```
const transaction = req.body.transaction
if (!transaction._id) transaction._id = new ObjectId()

// Use the findOneAndModify function with upsert to create or update the transaction
Transaction.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: transaction._id }, transaction, { upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err })
  }
  return res.status(200).json({ message: 'OK', result })
})
```

Model:

```
transaction.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function (next) {
  // count all totals for the details and update the TransactionTotal with this.
  const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery())
  if (!docToUpdate) {
    // code will reach this when the document is being upserted
    console.log('no doc found', this)
    return next()
  }
  let transactionTotal = 0
  let counter = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < docToUpdate.details.length; i++) {
    transactionTotal += docToUpdate.details[i].total
    counter++
    if (counter === docToUpdate.details.length) {
      this._update.transactionTotal = transactionTotal
      next()
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please share collection and what you want  at jsoneditor  online

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by setting the 'docToUpdate' with this._update.

The code in to hook function now looks like this, and that is working!

```
let docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery())
if (!docToUpdate) {
  // console.log('no doc found', this)
  // return next()
  docToUpdate = this._update
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how to get document that being deleted in the query middleware?

```
cartSchema.pre(/delete/i, async function (next) {
```